# Java process : Wait for parent process exits

Tags: java

My java application is launched by a parent process(windows) as its child process.

The parent process sends its PID in environment variable to child process.

In Windows API, there is a `WairForSingleObject` which allows the child process to wait for parent process exits (including process termination).

How can I monitor the parent process's exit in JAVA?

Comment: Wouldn't the child process be terminated anyways when the parent is terminated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JNA` to make use of `WaitForSingleObject`. All you have to do is adding `JNA` library to your classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

After that you can just call:

```
WinNT.HANDLE handle = Kernel32.INSTANCE.OpenProcess(0, false, pidOfAnyProcess);
Kernel32.INSTANCE.WaitForSingleObject(handle, Kernel32.INFINITE);
```

Comment: Thanks,  just one correction : the child process must obtain `WinNT.SYNCHRONIZE` access right when `OpenProcess` to wait for it.